# Fix an icon that can lead you to different websites based on platform

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<body>

<p class="fab fa-facebook-square" id="fb"></p>

<script>
var uagent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();{
function Detect();
{if (uagent.search("iphone"));
GetElementById("fb").href = "#";
else if (uagent.search("android");
GetElementById("fb").href = "#";
else (uagent.search("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 
Safari/537.36");
GetElementId("fb").href = "#";
}
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

i'm trying to get to different dites depending upon the platform. Basically the plan was to create an icon that would eithertake you to the website version of a page, or launch an app and open the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think this is what you are asking, you can check that it is working by changing the user agent in Chrome under "Network Conditions". Just uncheck set automatically and change to emulate the device you want to test.

```js
var uagent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
console.log(uagent)

function detectDevice() {
  if (uagent.indexOf("iphone") !== -1) {
    return "iphone"
  }
  if (uagent.indexOf("ipad") !== -1) {
    return "ipad"
  }
  if (uagent.indexOf("android") !== -1) {
    return "android"
  }
  return "desktop browser" 
}

function setLink(element) {
  const device = detectDevice()
  console.log(device)
  switch(device) {
    case "iphone":
      element.href="/iphone"
      break;
    case "ipad":
      element.href="/ipad"
      break;
    case "android":
      element.href="/android"
      break;
    default:
      element.href="/desktop"
      break;
  }
  console.log(element.href)
}

const element = document.getElementById("fb")
setLink(element)
```

```html
<p class="fab fa-facebook-square">
  <a id="fb" href="/fb">FB</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you, almost perfect, just had to change a couple of bits.